# Discord.js Userinfo command TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: discord, discord.js

I apologize for that, I really don't like asking for help, but I can't find a solution.

I am creating a userinfo command for my bot, so far so good, but I want to get information from a user who is not on the server where the command was executed, but he is on another server where the bot is, as I am using a function to collect the positions, I get an error, so I would like that, if the user is not on the bot server, he would return me another embed, containing only the account id, name and creation date information.

```
  async run({ message, args, prefix, author }, t) {
    moment.locale("pt-BR");

    try {
      const user = 
        this.client.users.cache.get(args[0]) ||
          message.mentions.members.first() ||
          message.author;

      const flags = [];
      this.Flags(user, flags);

      const roles = [];
      this.Roles(user, roles, message);

      let presence;
      if (!user.presence.activities.length) presence = "Não está jogando nada";
      else presence = user.presence.activities.join(", ");

      const device = this.Device(user);
      const joined = `${moment(user.joinedAt).format("L")} ( ${moment(
        user.joinedAt
      )
        .startOf("day")
        .fromNow()} )`;
      const created = `${moment(
        this.client.users.cache.get(user.id).createdAt
      ).format("L")} ( ${moment(this.client.users.cache.get(user.id).createdAt)
        .startOf("day")
        .fromNow()} )`;

      const USERINFO = new ClientEmbed(author)
        .setTitle(flags + ` ${user.username}`)
        .addFields(
          { name: "<:richPresence:843144574234394655>┆**Status:**", value: `\`\`\`diff\n- ${presence}\`\`\`` },
          { name: "**Nome do Usuário:**", value: user.tag, inline: true },
          {
            name: "**Nickname no Servidor:**",
            value: !!user.nickname ? user.nickname : "Nenhum Nickname",
            inline: true,
          },
          { name: "**ID do Usuário:**", 
            value: user.id,
            inline: true
          },
          { name: "**Conta Criada:**", value: created, inline: true },

          { name: "**Entrada no Servidor:**", value: joined, inline: true },
          {
            name: "**Dispositivo:**",
            value: String(device).replace("null", "Nenhum"),
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: `**Cargos no Servidor**`,
            value: roles,
          }
        )
        .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setFooter(
          `Comando solicitado por ${message.author.tag}`,
          message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
        );

      message.quote(USERINFO);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`ERRO NO COMANDO USERINFO\nERROR: ${err}`);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive your problem is that you are getting the account information as a `User` property.

The problem with this is that guild members and users are different. Guild members, hold additional information for a user in a specific server, such as roles.

Currently you get the profile information from this variable:

```js
const user = 
this.client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || // This is a user property
message.mentions.members.first() || // This is a member propery
message.author; // This is a user property
```

The problem with this, is that it sometimes it will return a user, which doesnt have any roles  stored in its data.

Here is a possible fix:

```js
 // We need to make sure they run this in a server so we can access the roles
if (!message.guild) return message.channel.send("This command must be ran in a server")

// This will always return a guild member
const user = 
    message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    message.member;
```

You can read about the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and [Member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) on the discord.js docs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Guild.member(User)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) to fetch the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) from the inputted user, or `null`.

If the result is `null`, then the user does not exist in the server.

```js
const user = 
  this.client.users.cache.get(args[0]) ||
  message.mentions.members.first() ||
  message.author;

// you should also probably check that the command is run in a guild channel

const guildMember = message.guild.member(user);

if (guildMember) {
  // include roles in embed
} else {
  // don't include roles in embed
}
```